# AJAX : Getting two different JSON variable from php using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am need to directly get the variable from the response.php which contains the needed value. How can I the filter that JSON variable separately? Or if i merge both array into 1 JSON call then how do i get the different value

AJAX

```
function getMaleRanking(){
var mr = 'maleRangking';
var mf = 'femaleRangking';

$.ajax({
    url : 'ajax/ajax_drill.php',
    type : 'post',
    cache : false,
    data :{ mr : mr , mf : mf , event_id : event_id},
    success:function(data){
        var rankings = data;
        //get the first json 
        //get the sencod json

    }
});
}
getMaleRanking();
```

My php

```
echo json_encode(resultMergeMale, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
echo json_encode(resultMergeFem, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: the `data` variable in `function(data){...}` of ajax call will hold anything which you php "echoed" to the output buffer

Comment: return the value with `json_encode`

Comment: Yes but i want is to filter one by one variable

Comment: Then inside your foreach you should append the values instead of overwriting it again and again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give response in json format for fetching valued in multiple paramater. Your php code should be

```
$response=array('mr'=>'','mf'=>'');
if(isset($_POST['mr'])){
   foreach ($resultMergeMale as $key => $value) {
       $firstval =  $value;
       //get this first val
       $response['mr'] . =$firstval; 
   }

}

if(isset($_POST['mf'])){
    foreach ($resultMergeFem as $key => $value) {
       $secondval = $value
        //get this seaond val
       $response['mf'] .= $secondval ;
    }
}

echo json_encode($response);
die();
```

You have to pass dataType:'json', so Jquery automatically convert JSON string into JSON object and you can access by its property. Your Ajax code should be

```
function getMaleRanking(){
var mr = 'maleRangking';
var mf = 'femaleRangking';

$.ajax({
    url : 'ajax/ajax_drill.php',
    type : 'post',
    cache : false,
    dataType:'json',
    data :{ mr : mr , mf : mf , event_id : event_id},
    success:function(data){
        alert(data.mr);
        alert(data.mf);
    }
});
}
getMaleRanking();
```

Comment: It works but i chaned   $response['mf']=>$secondval  to  $response['mf'] .= $secondval ;

Comment: ahh ok... I got CR but its from anonymous user

Comment: @EchoingThroughoutTelNumara I have made change on it :)

Answer (score 0):

Comma delimit the values, like this

```
if(isset($_POST['mr'])){
   foreach ($resultMergeMale as $key => $value) {
       $firstval =  $value;
       //get this first val

   }

}

if(isset($_POST['mf'])){
    foreach ($resultMergeFem as $key => $value) {
       $secondval = $value
        //get this seaond val
    }
}

echo $firstval.",".$secondval
```

And then in your Ajax call,

```
success:function(data){
        var rankings = data.split(",");
        var firstval = rankings[0];
        var secondval = rankings[1];
        //your logic here
  }
```